# EJB and JPA - persisting object with multiple EJBs

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I am actively learning JPA and EJBs and I came to the following situation: I have one EJB (named `SecondController`) which implements a method for persisting an entity. Let's call it `SecondEntity`. There is a requirement that when the entity is persisted its field `dateInserted` is set to the current date (in practice the requirements may be more complex - I want to know if the concept is OK or if I am going totally in the wrong direction).

Now I define a new entity - let's call it `FirstEntity` - which contains `SecondEntity` as an attribute. I implement another EJB which implements a method for persisting `FirstEntity` - so each time `FirstEntity` is persisted, `SecondEntity` must be persisted too. I know I can use `@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` on the `secondEntity` attribute in `FirstEntity` (that would do auto persist). But remember, there is a `dateInserted` requirement and logic is already implemented. The idea is to reuse the already implemented method for persisting `SecondEntity` in `SecondController` by injecting it into `FirstController`.

```
@Entity
public class SecondEntity implements Serializable
{
}

@Entity 
public class FirstEntity implements Serializable
{
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_id", referencedColumnName = "second_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private SecondEntity secondEntity;
}

@Stateless
public class SecondController implements Serializable
{
    @PersistenceUnit(name = "PU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public SecondController()
    {
    }

    public void create(SecondEntity secondEntity)
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try
        {
            secondEntity.setDateInserted(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            em.persist(secondEntity);
        }

        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
public class FirstController implements Serializable
{
    @PersistenceUnit(name = "PU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @EJB
    private SecondController secondController;

    public FirstController()
    {
    }


    public void create(FirstEntity firstEntity)
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try
        {
            secondController.create(firstEntity.getSecondEntity());
            em.persist(firstEntity);
        }

        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The point of the sample code above is to call `secondController.create(firstEntity.getSecondEntity())`. Is this OK or is it considered a bad practice? I have two such cases in my application and one works (`SecondEntity` is optional - can be `null`), and one which does not (`SecondEntity` is mandatory - cannot be `null`). The code fails at `em.persist(firstEntity)` by saying:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

If I replace the mentioned call with `em.persist(firstEntity.getSecondEntity)` the code works fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set the `dateInserted` field in your EJB. Do it in a `PrePersist` [event hook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events). This way the persistence provider will make sure your hook is always called automatically before persisting an entity. Then you can let persist to be cascaded from parent entity to the other (`@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`).

```
@Entity
public class SecondEntity implements Serializable {
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if (dateInserted == null) {
            dateInserted = new Date();
        }
    }
}
```